# getLoginStatus returns no session

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is anyone else experiencing an issue where FB.getLoginStatus is not returning a session for logged in users?  I created a bug on Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/128072900639318

Comment: I think you have to listen and respond to events.  FB.Event.Subscribe() http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the docs again http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ it seems they recommend checking the variable `response.status === 'connected'` instead of `response.session` when checking the response of FB.getLoginStatus.